# "view contact" not updating when changes are made

Tags: contacts, admin, cache

I do all my backend entry for CiviCRM on my "View Contact" page, but nothing I do is visible for about a day and it is causing a lot of stress for my staff.

If we go to the Membership tab and add a new membership, it will save, but it won't show up on the Membership tab until the next day. I've tried cleaning my cache in Joomla, and setting a rule to bypass admin for caching, but no luck!

Has anyone encountered this probelm?

Comment: Band-aid solution:
Found out that it was our web-browser's cache that was causing this problem, both in Chrome and Firefox. Chrome offers no way to turn caching off (except in development mode), so I installed a plugin to clear the cache anytime I need to confirm updated information.
I'm surprised others haven't posted about this problem since it must be fairly wide-spread.

Answer (score 1):

Band-aid solution:

Found out that it was our web-browser's cache that was causing this problem, both in Chrome and Firefox. Chrome offers no way to turn caching off (except in development mode), so I installed a plugin to clear the cache anytime I need to confirm updated information.

I'm surprised others haven't posted about this problem since it must be fairly wide-spread

Comment: never had such a problem and never heard it raised by others. not sure why you conclude this would be wide-spread

Comment: We are experiencing the same problem - has installing a cache cleaner continued to resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi LMK, yes the cache cleaner works everytime. We have to reload the page after cleaning the cache to see the updates though.